# How to finish edge of shower?

Tags: shower, waterproofing, kerdi

Trying to find the best way to finish a walk in, curbless shower?

I’ve got tile 55” out from the wall, of which then transitions to green board. However, there’s still enough splatter that I don’t like how wet the wall (mainly by the floor) is getting. I Kerdi membraned over the first 5 inches(to the right of my finger), but the splatter is getting about 10 inches past.

My thought was to extend Kerdi membrane another 3 ft just to be safe then mud/paint it to prevent gross, moldy drywall. Thoughts? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Put up a door.  Completely enclose your shower in glass.  Your curbless floor will be just as pretty and just as convenient if you complete the glass cubicle.

People seem to confuse "curbless" (which I happen to find nice) with "wet room" (which I think is great for prisons, high schools, and health clubs).  If you want an open shower room you need to design for it.  You would mud the entire floor, tile all the walls, and you wouldn't put a wood cabinet there.

Comment: Yes! Besides, Kerdi will prevent water from going into the drywall, but it won't prevent the wet paint from getting moldy.

Comment: @jay613 while I do not disagree, the cabinet is over 7 ft away. The picture was wide lens so it makes it look much closer. To clarify, it is not wet, more just light splatter, like you misted a bottle on it once. 


Tile is probably the safest bet?

Comment: Tiling the wall IMO is a big compromise.  If you tile 12 inches of it, it'll look like a big hack.  If you tile all the way to the wall on the right it will be expensive and will still look odd.  The floor outside the stall will still be soaked after every shower.  The grout lines in the new tile will still be darker in the wet spots than in the dry ones.  IMO if you want a compromise, try an 18-inch-wide glass wall extending from the rear wall.  That should keep the water off the painted wall without creating new problems.  But the remaining opening will look begging for door. :)